# ESP8266 with ESP12E web ip address not responding

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I have a program to control an RC car. The code compiles and uploads fine. It also prints out the ip address in the serial monitor. When i type the ip address into my browser i get an error that says the ip address can not be reached. Below is my code.

Thank you

Alex

```
 #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
 #include <WiFiClient.h>
 #include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
 #include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
```

// Define variables with the pin values

```
 const int DRIVE_MOTOR_POWER = D2;
 const int DRIVE_MOTOR_DIRECTION = D4;
 const int STEER_MOTOR_POWER = D1;
 const int STEER_MOTOR_DIRECTION = D3;
```

// drivePower sets how fast the car goes
// Can be set between 0 and 1023 (although car problaly wont move if values are too low)

```
 int drivePower = 1023;
```

// driveDirection sets what direction the car drives
// If the car is moving backwards when you press the forward button, change this to LOW

```
 uint8_t driveDirection = HIGH;
```

// steeringPower sets how fast the car turns
// Can be set between 0 and 1023 (again, car probably won't steer if the value is too low)

```
 int steeringPower = 1023;
```

// steerDirection sets what direction the car steers
// If the car is steering right when you press the left button, change this to LOW

```
 uint8_t steerDirection = HIGH;

 const char* ssid = "wifi_username";
 const char* password = "wifi_password";

 ESP8266WebServer server(80);

 void handleRoot() {

  server.send(200, "text/plain", String("Hello from esp8266!"));
 }

 void handleNotFound(){
   String message = "File Not Found\n\n";
   message += "URI: ";
   message += server.uri();
   message += "\nMethod: ";
   message += (server.method() == HTTP_GET)?"GET":"POST";
   message += "\nArguments: ";
   message += server.args();
   message += "\n";
   for (uint8_t i=0; i<server.args(); i++){
     message += " " + server.argName(i) + ": " + server.arg(i) + "\n";
   }
   server.send(404, "text/plain", message);
 }

 void setup(void){

   pinMode(DRIVE_MOTOR_POWER, OUTPUT);     
   pinMode(DRIVE_MOTOR_DIRECTION, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(STEER_MOTOR_POWER, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(STEER_MOTOR_DIRECTION, OUTPUT);

   Serial.begin(115200);
   WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
   Serial.println("");
```

// Wait for connection

```
   while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
     delay(500);
     Serial.print(".");
   }
   Serial.println("");
   Serial.print("Connected to ");
   Serial.println(ssid);
   Serial.print("IP address: ");
   Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

   server.on("/", handleRoot);

   server.on("/forward", [](){
     Serial.println("forward");
     analogWrite(DRIVE_MOTOR_POWER, drivePower);
     digitalWrite(DRIVE_MOTOR_DIRECTION, driveDirection);
     server.send(200, "text/plain", "forward");
   });

   server.on("/driveStop", [](){
     Serial.println("driveStop");
     analogWrite(DRIVE_MOTOR_POWER, 0);
     server.send(200, "text/plain", "driveStop");
   });

   server.on("/back", [](){
     Serial.println("back");
     analogWrite(DRIVE_MOTOR_POWER, drivePower);
     digitalWrite(DRIVE_MOTOR_DIRECTION, !driveDirection);
     server.send(200, "text/plain", "back");
   });

   server.on("/right", [](){
     Serial.println("right");
     analogWrite(STEER_MOTOR_POWER, steeringPower);
     digitalWrite(STEER_MOTOR_DIRECTION, steerDirection);
     server.send(200, "text/plain", "right");
   });

   server.on("/left", [](){
     Serial.println("left");
     analogWrite(STEER_MOTOR_POWER, steeringPower);
     digitalWrite(STEER_MOTOR_DIRECTION, !steerDirection);
     server.send(200, "text/plain", "left");
   });

   server.on("/steerStop", [](){
     Serial.println("steerStop");
     analogWrite(STEER_MOTOR_POWER, 0);
     server.send(200, "text/plain", "steerStop");
   });

   server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);

   server.begin();
   Serial.println("HTTP Server Started");
 }

 void loop(void){
   server.handleClient();
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you have connected to wi-fi?

These two lines looks incorrect:

```
const char* ssid = "wifi_username";
const char* password = "wifi_password";
```

It should be:

```
const char *ssid = "wifi_username";
const char *password = "wifi_password";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes i am sure it is connected. I can see it on my network and it shows its IP address after a successful connection.

Comment: If this does not solve the problem. I would suggest you search or post your question on [Arduino StackExchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Posted yesterday with no responses. Anyone else have any ideas?